# Four elements repetition in a texture

Tags: pattern

I have to create a texture using 4 different elements (call them A,B,C,D or whatever you want) on a 6x7 grid. The goal is to obtain a pattern with the least repetitions of the same element in horizontal, vertical and diagonal directions, especially, if possible, should be avoided to repeat the same element in adjacent blocks. I think there should be different solution to this, just answer with what you came up with.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're counting as a repetition.

Comment: I know this question sounds simple but is varies alot based on priority.  Is A and A being diagonally adjacent worse than horizontally adjacent?  Is A and A being diagonally adjacent worse than it having three As separate but in the same row?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:

$$a b c d a b\\
b c d a b c\\
c d a b c d\\
d a b c d a\\
a b c d a b\\
b c d a b c\\
c d a b a d\\$$

In the row you must have 2 repetitions and in the column 3.

Comment: If you look in diagonal, there is the same letter in each oblique line (going from lower left to upper right)

Comment: You are right! I missed diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the nucleus

$$a b a\\
b c b\\
a b a\\$$

add "layers" of two characters alternating onto the nucleus. For example, the next iteration will be

$$c d c d c\\
d a b a d\\
c b c b c\\
d a b a d\\
c d c d c\\$$

This array can be extended infinitely, and all elements of this infinite array will have neighbours in all 8 directions that are different from itself, except at the corners.

$$c d c d c d\\
a b a b a b\\
c d c d c d\\
a b a b a b\\
c d c d c d\\
a b a b a b\\
c d c d c d\\$$

Simply take a 6x7 subset of this infinite array at any position where no corner exists to produce an answer.